# does the complete url stay on a CNAME alias

Tags: url, cname

```
domain.com       A       IP
www.domain.com       CNAME   domain.com
```

In this scenario would www.domain.com/foo/bar point to domain.com/foo/bar?

Would the url still be www.domain.com/foo/bar

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, requests to `http://www.domain.com/` and `http://domain.com/` would connect to the same IP address but would use two distinct host names: `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` respectively.

There wouldn't be a redirection from `http://domain.com/` to `http://www.domain.com/` (or the other way around) unless the server was configured to do so (but this isn't directly linked to the DNS configuration, rather it's about the configuration of the HTTP server).

Comment: Thats great. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

The URL will stay the same. On DNS level your URL will be mapped to the same IP address as it is known for domain.com

So you will receive a request from www.domain.com

If you change the underlying IP address of domain.com it will automatically reflect to the CNAME alias www.domain.com